# Changing variable value in same session state

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a text field `P1_SHOW_DATA` which gets updated to value `'Y'` by a dynamic action upon clicking a button. And then this field is used in a SQL Query as

```
where :P1_SHOW_DATA='Y'
```

However, the value of `:P1_SHOW_DATA` is set to `'Y'` after first submit button press. I want the value of this variable to be reset to `'N'`, so that the user has to resubmit after changing the filters.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question.

Upon, adding a computation that fires 'Post Rendering' and execution point being 'After Regions', and setting the item value to a static value 'N', we can change the variable value in the same session state.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you're overcomplicating it.

- there's a page with a report (at least, that's what "SQL query" and "where" sound like)
- in order to display desired data, you have to set filters

  - I presume that those are additional items on the page
- once filters are set, user submits the page (by pushing the button)
- report fetches data

So far, so good. Now, let's change filters:

- well ... change them
- once new filters are set, user should submit the page (by pushing the button)
- report fetches new data, according to newly set filters

Why would you need `P1_SHOW_DATA`? Remove it and use the report *as is*.

Comment: I have multiple Select Lists which are dependent on each other but not in a parent-child relationship, so I have set their Page Action on Selection value as 'Redirect and Set Value'. If I don't use this variable P1_SHOW_DATA, then interactive grid populates the data with selected value in select list without the click of the submit button. In order to have the data populated only after all values are selected, I have introduced this variable, whose value gets populated as 'Y' with a dynamic action on Submit Button.

Comment: If those Select Lists depend on each other, why can't you use parent-child relationship? *How* do they depend on each other, then?

Comment: There is no specific order in which a user can select these filters. Values in other select lists need to be changed depending on the value chosen by the user in any select list. If I specify a parent-child relationship, values present in parent select list don't get updated when user selects a value in the child relationship. However, that's not the functionality I require to implement.

Comment: OK. It means that any Select List's query has WHERE clause which references other Select List items. Right? I just don't understand why can't you name all those items in "Parent Item(s)" property. I'm just trying to suggest something to make it simpler, if possible ... If nothing else works, create another button whose label is "Reset filters" which would set P1_SHOW_DATA to "N". Users will learn that they have to push it.